# How can I create stack bar chart in SwiftUI using iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, charts, ios15

I am new in SwiftUI and I am facing creating stack bar chart using iOS 15 and SwiftUI

My code is like this

```
struct StackedBarChartView: View {
    let dataPoints: [String]
    let dataSets: [[Int]]
    let colors: [Color]
    let fixedWidth: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(dataSets.indices) { index in
                            Spacer()
                            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                                ForEach(dataSets[index].indices) { innerIndex in
                                    let value = dataSets[index][innerIndex]
                                    let barHeight = CGFloat(value) / CGFloat(dataSets[index].reduce(0, +)) * geometry.size.height

                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                        .fill(colors[innerIndex % colors.count])
                                        .frame(width: fixedWidth, height: barHeight)
                                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            HStack {
                ForEach(dataPoints, id: \.self) { dataPoint in
                    Text(dataPoint)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .padding(.top, 8)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let dataPoints = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    let dataSets = [[20, 30, 40, 10], [10, 20, 30, 40], [5, 15, 10, 30]]
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .orange] // Define your desired colors here

    var body: some View {
        StackedBarChartView(dataPoints: dataPoints, dataSets: dataSets, colors: colors, fixedWidth: 10)
    }
}
```

But I am getting chart like this
[image]

But I want it to look like this

[image]

How can I show data on the left hand side of the graph. It is possible?

Comment: Are you asking about the y axis labels?

Comment: @koen Yes both y axis and x axis label

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label axes in Swift Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879128/how-to-label-axes-in-swift-charts)

Comment: @koen Charts is only above iOS 16 not in iOS 15

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: @koen Stack Bar chart is available in this?

Comment: OP made a custom Stack Bar Chart.

Comment: Place the Axis data with Spacers in HStacks or VStacks, and limit the width or height to the chart width or height. You may need to tweak it some, but you should be able to lay it out pretty easily